# Balanced-JS returns 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gruntjs, balanced-payments

I'm attempting to run the following sample:

https://github.com/balanced/balanced-js

I follow the README and got my local server running.  Now when I get to the website: [image: website] and click tokenize (with pre-populated data), I get the following:

```
{
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Cannot POST /v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP5noKWGqLyLOLKkQkJmKg9s/cards"
}
```

Is it supposed to return that for this example?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: As a potential documentation problem specific to balanced.js, this is better asked on the github issue tracker for balanced. Hit up https://github.com/balanced/balanced-js/issues and ask them if this is supposed to happen. That way the people making balanced.js know there might be a problem, which they won't if you post on SO

Comment: I actually went to the help chat room for Balanced Payments (off their website).  The guy there wasn't much help.  He just said I should try another example.

Comment: which is why you file an issue. It's more permanent, the rest of the world can discover it in perpetuity, and contributors other than "the person you chatted to" will be able to pitch in when they look at it, rather than having to have been then when you were in the chat room.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just updated the repo to point to our live backend. Would you do me a favor and pull `balanced-js` down, and try again.

```
cd balanced-js
git pull
```

Thanks.